# Show first 4 items inside div with class active rest without

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I got some projects that use a template layout/slider. The slider works by wrapping the first 4 projects in a div with class `active` and the rest inside divs without `active` but still grouped per 4.

I tried the following:

```
$tel = 1;
foreach($projectcr1 as $projects1) {
    $projectimages = $projects1['images']; // Get image parameters of the article
    $projectimgs = json_decode($projectimages); // Split the parameters apart

    if($projectimgs->image_intro != ''){
        $img = 'cms/'.$projectimgs->image_intro;
    }else{
        $img = 'cms/images/placeholder/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    if (strlen($projects1['introtext']) > 40){
       $shortstrproj = substr($projects1['introtext'], 0, 40) . '...';
    }else{
        $shortstrproj = $projects1['introtext'];
    }

    if($projects1['id'] != ''){

        if($tel == 1){
            $projecten1 .= '<div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">';
            }
    //Here I need the first 4 projects ($projecten1 below is one project being looped)
    $projecten1 .= '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 js-wpg-item" data-categories="'.$projects1['categorie_alias'].'">
            <a class="card portfolio-grid__card js-wpg-card" href="project/'.$projects1['content_alias'].'.html">
                <div class="imgwrapport">
                    <img width="360" height="180" src="'.$img.'" class="card-img-top  portfolio-grid__card-img" alt="photo1" srcset="'.$img.' 360w, '.$img.' 300w, '.$img.' 768w, '.$img.' 540w, '.$img.' 830w"
                        sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px">
                </div>
                <div class="card-block portfolio-grid__card-block">
                    <h5 class="card-title  ortfolio-grid__card-title">'.$projects1['title'].'</h5>
                    <p class="portfolio-grid__card-price">'.strip_tags($shortstrproj).'</p>
                    <div class="portfolio-grid__card-items">
                        <p class="portfolio-grid__card-item">
                            Bekijk project
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>';

if(($tel % 4) == 0){
    $projecten1 .= '</div></div><div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">';
        // Here I need the rest of the projects
        $projecten1 .= '</div></div>';
                }
                $tel++;
            }
        }
echo $projecten1;
?>
```

If `$tel` = 1 wrap the div with active around the items. Then when `$tel` % 4 leaves 0 (4 divided by 4 leaves 0), close the divs and start new ones but this time without the active class.

This works fine, my only issue is how to seperate the data. How can I show the first 4 projects inside the first div, and the rest in the following divs without active class?

Example how I want the code in the end:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
        project1
        project2
        project3
        project4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="row">
        project5
        project6
        project7
        project8
    </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="row">
        project9
        project10
        project11
        project12
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Code . if u have questions about the code just post under it.

```
<?php
$tel = 1;
$next_div = true;
$foreach_ended = 0;
// 2 New vars they are needed for the right output down

foreach($projectcr1 as $projects1) {
    $projectimages = $projects1['images']; // Get image parameters of the article
    $projectimgs = json_decode($projectimages); // Split the parameters apart

    if($projectimgs->image_intro != ''){
        $img = 'cms/'.$projectimgs->image_intro;
    }else{
        $img = 'cms/images/placeholder/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    if (strlen($projects1['introtext']) > 40){
       $shortstrproj = substr($projects1['introtext'], 0, 40) . '...';
    }else{
        $shortstrproj = $projects1['introtext'];
    }

    if($projects1['id'] != '')
    {
        $foreach_ended=0;
        // set to 0 when a DIV is Open.

        if($tel == 1&&$next_div==true){ /* set the first ACTIVE div with $next_div */
            $projecten1 .= '<div class="carousel-item active"><div class="row">';
            $next_div=false;  /* set it to false so every new 4xDIV is not Active */
        }
        elseif($tel == 1&&$next_div!=true)
        {
            $projecten1 .= '<div class="carousel-item"><div class="row">';
        }else{}

        $projecten1 .= '
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 js-wpg-item" data-categories="'.$projects1['categorie_alias'].'">
                <a class="card portfolio-grid__card js-wpg-card" href="project/'.$projects1['content_alias'].'.html">
                    <div class="imgwrapport">
                        <img width="360" height="180" src="'.$img.'" class="card-img-top  portfolio-grid__card-img" alt="photo1" srcset="'.$img.' 360w, '.$img.' 300w, '.$img.' 768w, '.$img.' 540w, '.$img.' 830w"
                            sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block portfolio-grid__card-block">
                        <h5 class="card-title  ortfolio-grid__card-title">'.$projects1['title'].'</h5>
                        <p class="portfolio-grid__card-price">'.strip_tags($shortstrproj).'</p>
                        <div class="portfolio-grid__card-items">
                            <p class="portfolio-grid__card-item">
                                Bekijk project
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>';

        if(($tel % 4) == 0){
            $tel=1; /* reset Tel */
            $projecten1 .= '</div></div>'; /* End DIV when 4x is reached */
            $foreach_ended=1; /* set DIV to closed */
        }
        else
        {
            $tel++;
        }
    }
}
if($foreach_ended==0){$projecten1 .= '</div></div>';} /* when the Foreach enden and the LAST div had less then 4 items its not marked as CLOSED . so this IF closes the last open DIV */
echo $projecten1;
?>
```

Comment: It works, but can you give some explanation what you did?